# Template Argument Deduction for Tuple Index

Tags: c++, templates

```
template < typename TYPE, typename TUPLE, int INDEX >
void fun( TYPE& a, TUPLE b )
{
  a = std::get<INDEX>( b );
}
```

Calling the above is tedious:

```
//...
using tuple_t = std::tuple<int, double, double>;
double d;
fun<double, tuple_t, 1>( d, std::make_tuple( 1, 2.3, 4.5 ) );
//...
```

Is there **a better way**? For instance:

```
fun( d, std::make_tuple( 1, 2.3, 4.5 ), 1 );
```

Comment: There's `std::get` version taking a type as a parameter, rather than an index. You could write `std::get<TYPE>(b)` and not pass index at all.

Comment: Alternatively, make `INDEX` the first template parameter rather than the last, and you can write `fun<1>( d, std::make_tuple( 1, 2.3 ));`. That's about the same length as your preferred syntax.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for your first suggestion, but the type might not be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `int INDEX` the **first** template parameter. Specify it when calling the function, and allow the other parameters to be deduced: `fun<1>(d, std::make_tuple(1, 2.3))`.